# Disabling variables in connector depending on boolean

Tags: modelica

I'm building electrical models that use a complex number or just the real part of a variable in a connector. Depending on a boolean I am switching between the two equation sets.
My question is: What is the best way to handle the imaginary when I don't want to use it. Setting it to zero leads to problems when I connect other components that do the same because the variable is overdetermined. 
Is there a way to disable the imaginary part or change the connector so it only has a real variable if I use the real valued equation set?
Below I pasted the equation set.

```
equation 
   if transient then
     v = Complex(Vnom*cos(theta + phiV),0); // how can I avoid setting im to zero here?
   else
     v = Complex(Vnom*cos(phiV), Vnom*sin(phiV));
   end if;
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an analogous issue in both fluid problems and multibody problems.  In the fluid case, the "equation of state" changes which influences how many degrees of freedom there are.  In the case of multibody systems, you have the issue that you need some kind of mechanical ground element but if you have a "loop" in your components it will be over constrained.

It seems to me your issue is closer to the fluid problem (but I don't now the AC domain well at all, so I'm just guessing).  In that case, what you can do is cascade down through the hierarchy information about exactly what kind of formulation to use.  If you want to use different connectors, then you use a `replaceable` `package` to cascade new connector types through the hierarchy.  This gets kind of involved.  If, however, you just want to know whether to use one equation or the other (across a bunch of components), then you can just cascade a (`Boolean`?) parameter value through everything (*e.g.,* your `transient` flag).

Another thing you might consider is using `inner` and `outer` to implicitly cascade a parameter through your hierarchy.  Several libraries use a so-called `world` object to provide global information about the model.  In this way, you can put an `inner` `world` object at the root and all components within the same hierarchy can access it using the `outer` keyword.  I try to avoid `inner`/`outer` and use the more explicit parameter cascading.  But it is up to you.

Comment: Your suggestion of 'replaceable package' sounds interesting. Do you think it's possible to do something like 'redeclare connectorA if transient'?

Comment: No, what I mean is that you would create two different packages, one with the transient connector and one with the steady state connetor.  Then you'd do `redeclare package Connectors = TransientConnectors`.  No `if` involved, you just choose which connector you want.

Comment: The `Modelica.Fluid` and `Modelica.Media` libraries are good examples of this pattern.  Again, since I don't know your domain, I cannot say if this is the best pattern, just that it is "a" pattern.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, this requires to build the network again with models which redeclare the transient connector when I want to do transient simulations. I think then it's better to keep the same connector for different models and set the imaginary part to zero. Like that it's possible to simulate steady state/transient behavior without reconnecting the models. Anyway, thank you for your advice Michael =)

Comment: Just a note.  You don't need to reconnect anything.  To switch between the different connectors, all you need to do is change on definition at the root of your model and all models underneath it will then adjust accordingly.  Nevertheless, it is still a pretty complicated construction with lots of package propagation.